# How can I use the undo function in dojox?

Tags: javascript, dojo, undo

We are using Dojo toolkit on our whole project. Now I want to add undo function. For example: When you press `ctrl + z`, the system goes one step back. I found undo function from Dojox. But I just can't successfully use it, because the documentary is so unclear.

Here is the usage that I found in the Dojox documentary:

```
var foo = new Undo(options);
foo.undo();
```

But `options` is undefined.
I don't know what should I write as `options`.
How can i use the undo from Dojox? What is the detailed usage?

Comment: options is optional object with "settings"

Comment: could you please give a small example?

Comment: send me link to the docs, where you have found this piece of code (couldn't google that)

Comment: https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/drawing/manager/Undo

Answer (score 0):

according to the source code... `1.16.3`

the only accepted part of options are the `keys` to bind `ctrl-z` and `ctrl-y`

if you don't need keybinding use empty options:

```js
var foo = new Undo({}); // empty options
foo.undo();
```

or pass `options.keys` require singleton `keys` or use existing instance

```js
require(["dojo/keys"], function(keys) {
    var foo = new Undo({keys: keys}); // pass options.keys = obtained singleton keys
    foo.undo(); 
});
```

Comment: still not working...here is my code.......`                                                                                                      var foo = new Undo({keys: keys});  
   if (event.ctrlKey == true && event.keyCode == 90) {
    foo.undo(); 
   }`

Comment: check source code - it's listening for keys already inside, use debugger...